# How to increase the height of a line in a plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am currently working on a graph in which I have a dataset where lines have to be drawn between each two points. It can for example represent the duration of operations in time, with pauses inbetween.

My dataset consists of two columns. The first column contains the first x-coordinate, and the second column contains the second x-coordinate. The line will be drawn between each row combination of these two coordinates, where the y-coordinate here will be equal to 1. In other words, they will be drawn on a horizontal line.

My current code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,10))
count = 1

for j in data.index:
    row = data.loc[j, :]
    ax.plot(row, [count,count], color = 'b', linewidth = 1)

ax.set_xticks(tuple(range(3,121,7)))
ax.set_xticklabels(tuple(range(1,18)))
```

and my result is shown in the figure below. [image: test]

where the x-axis represents weeks.

The issue that I am having is that I want this to be more visible, because it is rather small now. One way to do this is by using the linewidth and set this to for example 12. However, I found out that this does not only increase the HEIGHT but also the WIDTH, leading to a wrong representation of the time as is shown in the figure below.

[image]

The periods are suddenly much longer and sometimes even 'melt' together. Hence, my question is: **How can I increase the thickness of the line without increasing the width?**

I am really looking forward to suggestions!